# Honeycomb border

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add borders to a jQuery honeycomb plugin (http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-For-Responsive-Hexagon-Grid-Layout-Honeycombs.html) however I can't seem to get it to work since the Honeycumb shape itself is build on a different way than shapes CSS supports itself.
When I add `border-top` and `border-bottom` the lines show up as expected:

```
.honeycombs .hex_inner{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    /* Border */
    border-top: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
}
```

Result:

[image]

But the left and right attributes are not working the same way when I just use the border tag itself, it looks like they show up inside the honeycomb instead of outside.

```
.honeycombs .hex_inner{
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;

}
```

Result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, is there a way to add a white border easier in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Add a larger white honecomb behind the original honeycomb seems easiest solution to me.

Besides that you can try using a box-shadow.

You can consider an svg element for the honecomb too.